# wxWidgets string on windows

Tags: wxwidgets, utf-16, wxstring

I have this code:

```
wxString tmp(wxT("Información del usuario"));
wxStaticBoxSizer* sbSizer1 = new wxStaticBoxSizer (wxVERTICAL, panel, tmp);
```

This shows rare symbols instead of **ñ** in Windows but in Linux it shows correctly the letter..any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the string in your code depends on the encoding of your source file and also the charset used by your compiler. If your source file itself is in Unicode (whether it's UTF-8 or UTF-16), then you can use `L"..."` to create a wide string literal. If not, or you're not sure, you can always use `wxString::FromUTF8()` to explicitly encode the string as UTF-8, e.g. `wxString::FromUTF8("Informaci\xc3\xb3n...")` will always work.